# How to plot a variable to find out whether there is negative linear trend

Tags: r, regression

My data consists of new product introductions and after finding the parameters of the Bass model, I would like to know whether there is a negative linear trend over time. The parameter m stands for the number of ultimate adopters.

As could be seen from the outcome of the regression model, it seems that there is a negative trend. But how can I plot this nicely?

My dataset consists of product level data. The variable Date indicates what year the new product was launched (2009:2015) and the m indicates the parameter estimation of the bass model (continuous).

```
LM <- lm(m ~ Date, data = TotalBassModel1)


m          Estimate Std. Error t-value  Pr(>|t|)   
Intercept   371.51  29.10   12.766  < 2e-16 ***
Date2010    -18.74  27.87   -0.672  0.50132
Date2011    -71.41  27.30   -2.616  0.00893 **
Date2012    -71.03  26.17   -2.714  0.00669 **
Date2013    -137.07 25.32   -5.414  6.62e-08 ***
Date2014    -170.25 25.15   -6.770  1.53e11 ***
Date2015    -223.50 35.63   -6.273  4.03e10 ***
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Answer (score 0):

First I think you can treat your date as a numeric variable, by removing the "Date" characters before the date and setting it to numeric using as.numeric().

It will then gives you a proper adjustement with one coefficient that relate m to Date.

You can then plot your regression by using the predict() function, or by using ggplot functions http://t-redactyl.io/blog/2016/05/creating-plots-in-r-using-ggplot2-part-11-linear-regression-plots.html

Answer (score 0):

`boxplot(m ~ Date, data = TotalBassModel1)`

should give you a 5 number summary for each of the 7 years in your dataset. If the data are symmetric, then the mean is the median, and it is a nice way to robustly visualize trends in datasets with ordered categorical predictors, with either big or small sample sizes.